# How do I create a folder for special downloads

Tags: directory

I am 70 years old and brand new to Ubuntu. I am currently running v16.04.

I want to download music scores to a folder that is dedicated to that type of file.

Please, how do I do this?

Please keep in mind that I know **nothing** about Linux or Ubuntu. Please give clear and precise instructions.

Comment: Well,  there already exists default folder for Music , in your home folder. You can set firefox to ask you where to save files , and when you save a file , direct it to Music folder. Or you want an automatic answer ? Because that is definitely scriptable

Comment: What type (extension) would the scores be?

Comment: The scores are pdf files. Please, how do I set firefox to download to the music folder. Please be clear and detailed in your answer. I know nothing about any OS except windoze. Thank you very much, TomD

Answer (score 2):

In Firefox go to `Edit > Preferences` in the menu bar and under the General tab go to Downloads and change the option from `Save files to` to `Always ask me where to save files`.

[image: Firefox Settings]

Now when you click to download a file and select the `Save File` option a Window will appear where you can select the directory you wish to save the file to.

[image: File Dialog]